# Add items to local storage across multiple pages

Tags: javascript, local-storage

There are two files. The first:

```
<div class="someclass">text1</div>
<div class="someclass">text2</div>

<script>
  var foo = document.getElementsByClassName("someclass");
  var arr = Array.prototype.map.call(foo, function(elem) {
    return elem.innerHTML;
  });
  localStorage.foobar = JSON.stringify(arr);
  alert(localStorage.foobar);
</script>
```

That gives: `["text1","text2"]`

The second (files are identical except inner text in first two lines):

```
<div class="someclass">text3</div>
<div class="someclass">text4</div>

<script>
  var foo = document.getElementsByClassName("someclass");
  var arr = Array.prototype.map.call(foo, function(elem) {
    return elem.innerHTML;
  });
  localStorage.foobar = JSON.stringify(arr);
  alert(localStorage.foobar);
</script>
```

That gives: `["text3","text4"]`

I would like the second file to give `["text1","text2","text3","text4"]`, or maybe `["text3","text4","text1","text2"]`.

How can I do that?

Comment: each page should read the localStorage.foobar, and add her text if not already in. the 2 pages are run at the same time ?

Comment: Thanks for correction. The second page will be loaded after the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concat the both arrays after retrieving localStorage's contents first, using `JSON.parse()`:

```
var foo = document.getElementsByClassName("someclass");
var arr = Array.prototype.map.call(foo, function(elem) {
    return elem.innerHTML;
});
localStorage.foobar = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(localStorage.foobar).concat(arr));
console.log(localStorage.foobar);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to retrieve the previously-stored data (if any), and append to that array. Something like:

```js
var foostr = localStorage.foobar || "[]";
arr = JSON.parse(foostr);

var foo = document.getElementsByClassName("someclass");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(foo, function(elem) {
  arr.push(elem.innerHTML);
});

localStorage.foobar = JSON.stringify(arr);
alert(localStorage.foobar);
```

Comment: Yes, this works, so I upvoted, thanks, although `concat` method looks more understandable for me (I'm just novice at javascript).

Answer (score 1):

So you need to see if there is anything and concatenate it to the array.

```
if (localStorage.foobar) {
    var prev = JSON.parse(localStorage.foobar);
    arr = arr.concat(prev);
}
localStorage.foobar = JSON.stringify(arr);
```